# how to add a column at a specific position in a table which contain info about other data?

Tags: python, pandas

We have:

```
         Id    1   2    3   4
image_0.jpg    1   NA   0   1
image_1.jpg    NA  0    0   0
image_2.jpg    1   1    0   0
image_3.jpg    1   1    0   0
image_4.jpg    1   1    0   0
image_5.jpg    NA  0    1   NA
image_6.jpg    1   1    0   0
```

Expected:

```
         Id  types of attr    1   2    3   4
image_0.jpg   ['1','4']       1   NA   0   1
image_1.jpg   []              NA  0    0   0
image_2.jpg   ['1','2']       1   1    0   0
image_3.jpg   ['1','2']       1   1    0   0
image_4.jpg   ['1','2']       1   1    0   0
image_5.jpg   ['3']           NA  0    1   NA
image_6.jpg   ['1','2']       1   1    0   0
```

If there are 1s in the column only add column no to the new columns. Otherwise, ignore others.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```py
cols = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

df['types of attr'] = df[cols].eq(1).apply(lambda row: row.index[row].tolist(), axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

            Id    1    2  3    4 types of attr
0  image_0.jpg  1.0  NaN  0  1.0        [1, 4]
1  image_1.jpg  NaN  0.0  0  0.0            []
2  image_2.jpg  1.0  1.0  0  0.0        [1, 2]
3  image_3.jpg  1.0  1.0  0  0.0        [1, 2]
4  image_4.jpg  1.0  1.0  0  0.0        [1, 2]
5  image_5.jpg  NaN  0.0  1  NaN           [3]
6  image_6.jpg  1.0  1.0  0  0.0        [1, 2]
```